# Dynamic menu/create controller for menu?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm building a small app in CI. I'm using a pre-made template with a separate menu file. That menu file gets included in the pageview:

```
<?php include('include/sidebar.php'); ?>
```

Now I want to make the items in the menu dynamic based on the user permissions. In my sidebar.php I define the menu items like this:

```
<?php

$classname = "logs";
if (check_class($classname) == true){
    ?>
    <li id="<? echo $classname;?>" class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(1)==$classname){echo "active";}?>">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-toggle">
            <i class="material-icons">youtube_searched_for</i>
            <span><?php echo $this->lang->line('menu_logs') ?></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="ml-menu">

            <?php
            $methodname = "viewlogs";
            if (check_method($classname,$methodname) == true){
                ?>
                <li id="<? echo $classname;?>" class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(1)==$classname AND $this->uri->segment(2)==$methodname){echo "active";}?>">
                    <a href="<?= base_url($classname."/".$methodname); ?>"><?php echo $this->lang->line('menu_logs') ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php }?>

        </ul>
    </li>

<?php }?>
```

check_class and check_method are currently included in the sidebar.php file as well:

```
<?php

// This should not be here...

global $thisglobal;
$thisglobal = $this;

global $auth_roleglobal;
$auth_roleglobal = $auth_role;

function check_class($class) {
    global $thisglobal;

    //Override if admin
    if ($thisglobal->auth_role == "admin") {
        return true;
    }

    // Get current roles permissions
    $role_arr_flipped     = array_flip(array($thisglobal->auth_role)); // Avoid Error @ Only variables should be passed by reference
    $role_arr_intersected = array_intersect_key($thisglobal->config->item('user_role_permissions'), $role_arr_flipped);
    $role_perms           = array_shift($role_arr_intersected);

    if (array_key_exists($class, $role_perms)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function check_method($class,$method) {
    global $thisglobal;

    //Override if admin
    if ($thisglobal->auth_role == "admin") {
        return true;
    }

    // Get current roles permissions
    $role_arr_flipped     = array_flip(array($thisglobal->auth_role)); // Avoid Error @ Only variables should be passed by reference
    $role_arr_intersected = array_intersect_key($thisglobal->config->item('user_role_permissions'), $role_arr_flipped);
    $role_perms           = array_shift($role_arr_intersected);

    // Flip arrary
    $role_perms["$class"] = array_flip($role_perms["$class"]);

    if (array_key_exists($method, $role_perms["$class"])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

This works, but obviously including those functions into the view file is against the MVC approach, and I might want to reuse check_class and check_method in other views as well. I have moved those functions to my_controller, but again I should not call those functions from my view.

I am kinda lost in how to continue...

The sidebar does not have its own controller. Should I create a separate one? But then how do I load it because I can't (should not) call the menu controller from the page view.

Or should I call the check_class and check_method before loading the view, but I don't know yet which menu items I should check at that point.

Thanks!

Comment: There's one more thing that I forgot to mention, you said that one of your options was to load a controller to take care of that part the menu. I'd say that something like that would go into the HMVC convention and not the MVC. There's a lib that turns your default CI into HMVC. Look that up too and see if that's an option for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a library called Menu.php in there I would create functions that would check the user permissions and stuff, and also have a render method that will just output the menu.

This way your controller would load that library. Send some data into it and get the menu as a string. Then you just send that string to the view and echo it.

Other option would be looking into a presenter pattern and try to implement that in codeigniter.

[Presenter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter)

[Presenter library for ci](https://github.com/druu/ci-presenter)